# Unable to set cell colour on a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a simple for each loop checking the text in the 10th cell of my gridview, then setting the colour of that cell to green or red dependant in the text.

This is working fine apart from the very first cell in the first row is being ignored. Ive had similar situations to this with for loops, but not a for each.

Heres my code:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView vg = GridView1;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in vg.Rows)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[10].Text == "Order has been dispatched.")
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[10].BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
                }

                if (e.Row.Cells[10].Text == "Order is being processed.")
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[10].BackColor = Color.Red;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe the RowType isn't what you expect or there's some white space in the text value. Have you walked through this code while debugging?

Comment: Debug your code step by step and see what's happen there.

Comment: Yes I would agree with the above comments, maybe your row type for the first row is setup differently and is a completely different type than an 'DataRow'.  Like an 'EmptyDataRow' for instance.  I guess it depends on how you are binding it.

Comment: Like if you are adding an empty row to the GridView to force the headers to show up. (As an example)

Comment: Thanks all, I actually went a different route and counted all the rows in the grid, then set them from there and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help.  Probably not.  But you have redundant code.  Change your code to the following and make sure the event handler gets called for each row.  I don't think you have to make sure the GridViewRow.RowType is a DataRow, since you will only get this event on a DataRow.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[10].Text == "Order has been dispatched.")
       e.Row.Cells[10].BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
    if (e.Row.Cells[10].Text == "Order is being processed.")
        e.Row.Cells[10].BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```